# Getting listing of all available data passed with an event

Tags: event-observer

I'm working with this event dispatch: `dispatchEvent('nextbits_form_save_after',array('form_data'=>$params, 'form_model'=>$formModel));` but I don't have any documentation on it.

The event fires after a contact form is submitted, and I need to do some routing to deliver the posted data to specific email addresses based on some of the choices on the form, etc. How can I get a listing or enumeration of the data that is passed with the event?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData(‘form_data’);
```

and then

```
foreach ($request as $k => $v) $output .= "Key: '".$k."' | Value: ".$v."<br>";
```

...but I get no response from that....

Comment: put here your observer code...

Comment: Haven't really put anything together yet. I need to pass the form information to an email recipient. And also need to route the email to an appropriate recipient based on the Country and/or State data submitted with the form. My problem is, I need to layout the data to construct the email message as well as code the logic to properly send the email...but I have no idea what data (or what it's called) is coming over with the event....

Comment: Did you try `$this->getRequest()` and/or '$this->getRequest()->getParams()`?

Comment: I did try `$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParams();` 
and 
` = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()`, but don't seem to get anything back.

Comment: Just tried this:
`$event = $observer->getEvent();

$formData = $event->getFormData(); // magic get/set

$formModel = $event->getFormModel(); // magic get/set

$fd = zend_debug::dump($formData);
$fm = zend_debug::dump($formModel);`

Comment: Not sure if this is not returning anything, or I'm just not using what it returns properly. I'm looking to send the output to myself via email... would I assign the output of the debug statement to a variable and include that in the body of the email, or iterate through the $formData variable in the body of the email.... I'm assuming there's an array in there somewhere.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request object is not part of the observer object. 
So (i believe) the only solution to get to this data is to use `Mage::app()->getRequest()` from within your flow to get the request object. From there on you probably know the rest of the way with `getParams()` etc.

Comment: Thanks... I must not be doing it right.
`$observer = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData(‘form_data’);
foreach ($request as $k => $v) $Body .= "Key: '".$k."' | Value: ".$v."<br>";`
...no output at all.

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong unfortunately. Try doing the following `$request = Mage::app()->getRequest()` and then `$request->getData()` contains all your needed data. Currently you are mixing the request syntax with observer type syntax, hence it does not work. If this solves your issues, please mark this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yes! This works: `$event = $observer->getEvent();
        $formData = $event->getFormData();
  $formModel = $event->getFormModel();
  echo "<pre>";
  print_R($formData);
  print_R($formModel);` for what I need.
Thank you @Tim

Comment: Superb, good to hear!